# Looking for an Equivalent to the AWL for Academic Idioms

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, idiom-requests

Coxhead developed and evaluated something called the "Academic Word List" for English Language Learners. This is a list of (supposedly) the most common "academic" terms
to be used by students from non-English speaking countries to prepare them to study
in countries like the States, Canada, Ireland, Wales, Scotland, England, New Zealand, and Australia.

Does anyone have an idea if there is an "Academic Idioms List?" I've search over 30 websites and only found, for example, the top 50 English Idioms or the top 100 English Idioms. But I'm looking for a list that focuses more on "academic" idioms like "shed light on,"
"take advantage of," and so forth.

I have the Cambridge and Oxford English Idioms Dictionaries, but again, these offer all
kinds of idioms. I'm focused on finding "academic-based" ones.

Much thanks!!!!!

Comment: Even a partial list would be helpful. Cheers! Or if you know of someone who is in the midst of working on one.

Comment: Is *take advantage of* an idiom?

Comment: It may be relevant to mention that the use of idioms is strongly discouraged in serious/formal academic writing. Perhaps that explains the difficulty in finding such a list as the OP is looking for.

Comment: There might be value in selecting quality research from different areas and exposing the students directly to this content.

Comment: "Yes," take advantage is an idiom. Although, some might refer to it as a multi-word phrase. But here's the catch, it appears in many "idiom" dictionaries and on many idiom sites. It does, however, fit the definition for a non-transparent idiom.

Comment: And idioms are by NO means discouraged in academic use. Take a look at any article from neuroscience to linguistics and you will see many idioms within. Go to an American lecture at any university and you will see /hear them as well.

Comment: Recent research (Liu) showed professors using idioms about every 3-4 minutes in a lecture.

Comment: I realize you would like a useful list, which I don't have (I'm waiting for a good answer to your question as well), but of related interest is an article in TESOL Quarterly Vol.37 No.3 Autumn 2003 - A Corpus-Based Study of Idioms in Academic Speech.

Comment: Excellent. I'll take a look at that for starters. Thanks!

Comment: This treads a fine line between idioms and buzzwords/corporate-speak.  Perhaps some search into those realms is worth your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.